# Controllers in simulator unresponsive (chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, unity-game-engine, controller, simulator, airconsole

I have loaded the pong example with Unity. But when the controllers launch in the simulator in chrome (same issue on firefox), the controllers are unresponsive.

There are some errors in the chrome console:
[Log of simulator in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53mGU.png)

Does anyone have the same problem and can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text, not images. See [ask] and [this meta discussion on why code should not be posted as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get in the console are most likely unrelated to the controllers being unresponsive. (I get the same errors but my controllers work)

The AirConsole Unity Plugin has been updated again today, I recommend getting the [newest version from Github](https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin).